# Marking favorites in django object set

Tags: python, django

I have a table called `Tip` and table called `FavoritedTips`. Users favorite Tips in my app and the tip ID and user ID are added to the favoritedTips table.

```
class FavoritedTip(models.Model):
    tip = models.ForeignKey(Tip)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I now need to put a star next to the tip when the tips appear in the list. But of course     `tips = Tip.objects.filter(list=list)` doesn't have a tip.favoritedtip column.

What's the easiest thing to do in my template to know which tip has been favorited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to display a list of tips and for each one you need to know if this is a favorite of the current user.

You can do it with a custom `templatetag` if you really want to do that at the template level, but you'd better build your data structure in the view :

```
tips = Tips.objects.filter(my_filters)
user_favorite_tips = request.user.favoritedtip_set.values_list('pk', flat=True)
tips = [{'tip': tip, 
         'is_favorite': tip.pk in user_favorite_tips and True or False}
         for tip in tips]
```

And then in your template :

```
<ul>
{% for tip in tips %}
    <li>{{ tip.tip.as_html }} 
        {% if tip.is_favorite %} <img src="star.png" />{% endif %}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `tip.pk in user_favorite_tips and True or False` Isn't the second part of this a tautology?

Comment: @stan the problem i'm having with this is when there isn't a logged in user

Comment: @Brenden, this is not a problem. If your user is not logged in, you still have an `AnonymousUser` instance which behave the same. Take a deep look in the `auth` package documentation.

Comment: @Stan I get a "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'favoritedtip_set'" error

Comment: Just check if `user.is_anomymous()` and if `True` set `user_favorite_tips = []`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 queries by doing the following:

1: Create a `set` containing the IDs of the tips that the current user has favorited

```
favorite_set = set(Tip.objects.filter(favoritedtip_set__user__exact=currentUser).values_list('id',flat=True))
```

2: (you probably want to do this in the template)For each Tip object, check if that object's ID is in `favorite_set`. If it is, put a star next to it.

Comment: Do you know how I'd do #2 in the template?

Comment: Pass it in as a context variable: `return render_to_response('template.html', {'favorite_set':favorite set})` Then in your template, have an if statement `{% if tip.id in favorite_set %}<p>This tip is a favorite</p>{% endif %}`